# How to get KML Polygon and Multigeometry values in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, kml

I can read and get the KML data Placemark values using this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> placemarks = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Placemark").ToList();
            List<string> states = placemarks.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "name").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

But I don't know how to get the KML data if it has the following details:

1. **Example** : Alabama state KML format like

   `<Polygon> <outerBoundaryIs> <LinearRing> <coordinates>-85.070067,31.980703,0.0 -85.11515,31.907425,0.0 -85.135567,31.854884,0.0 -85.0567,32.017377,0.0 -85.070067,31.980703,0.0</coordinates> </LinearRing> </outerBoundaryIs> </Polygon>`
2. **Example** : Texas state KML format like

   `<MultiGeometry> <Polygon> <outerBoundaryIs> <LinearRing> <coordinates>-161.333785,58.703653</coordinates> </LinearRing> </outerBoundaryIs> </Polygon> <Polygon> <outerBoundaryIs> <LinearRing> <coordinates>-131.594177,55.106316,55.23548,0.0</coordinates> </LinearRing> </outerBoundaryIs> </Polygon> </MultiGeometry>`

I tried this `LINQ` procedure to get the Polygon values :

```
List<string> states = placemarks.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Polygon").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Output:

> -85.070067,31.980703,0.0 -85.11515,31.907425,0.0 -85.135567,31.854884,0.0 -85.0567,32.017377,0.0 -85.070067,31.980703,0.0

After I tried to replace the coordinates in the format shown below and copy/paste them into fusion table location preview, the map worked exactly as expected.

```
<Polygon> <outerBoundaryIs> <LinearRing> <coordinates>-85.070067,31.980703,0.0 -85.11515,31.907425,0.0 -85.135567,31.854884,0.0 -85.0567,32.017377,0.0 -85.070067,31.980703,0.0</coordinates> </LinearRing> </outerBoundaryIs> </Polygon>
```

But when I tried to get Multigeometry value using the same way :

```
List<string> states = placemarks.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "MultiGeometry").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

I got this output:

> -161.333785,58.703653 -131.594177,55.106316,55.23548,0.0

But I don't know how to get the details.

Answer (score 0):

> "*After I tried to replace the coordinates in the format shown below and copy/paste them into fusion table location preview, the map worked exactly as expected.*"
>
> `<Polygon> <outerBoundaryIs> <LinearRing> <coordinates>-85.070067,31.980703,0.0 -85.11515,31.907425,0.0 -85.135567,31.854884,0.0 -85.0567,32.017377,0.0 -85.070067,31.980703,0.0</coordinates> </LinearRing> </outerBoundaryIs> </Polygon>`

If you want the XML markup of the `XElement`, simply call `ToString()` instead of getting `Value` property of it :

```
List<string> states = placemarks.Descendants()
                                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "MultiGeometry")
                                .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                .ToList();
```

..or if you actually meant to get individual coordinates value from `MultiGeometry` :

```
List<string> states = placemarks.Descendants()
                                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "MultiGeometry")
                                .Descendants()
                                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Polygon")
                                .Select(x => x.Value)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: How to get MultiGeometry value for based on name like AK or AL.   Example : List<XElement> MultiGeometry = doc.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "MultiGeometry") && (? == "AK")).ToList();